# JpaRepository does not save the object in the database

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save an object of the Weather in the database, but it is not saved and no errors are issued. What could be the problem?

```
package com.example.Testww.rep;

import com.example.Testww.Weather;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface WeatherRepository extends JpaRepository<Weather, Long> {
}
```

package com.example.Testww;

```
import com.example.Testww.rep.WeatherRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/weather")
public class Controller {

WeatherService weatherService;
@Autowired
public Controller(WeatherService weatherService){
    this.weatherService= weatherService;
}
@GetMapping("/save")
public void SsaveWeather(){
    Weather weather = new Weather();
    weather.setHumidity(5.5);
    weather.setTemperature(15.5);
    weatherService.saveWeather(weather);
}
}
```

package com.example.Testww;

```
import com.example.Testww.rep.WeatherRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class WeatherService {

WeatherRepository weatherRepository;
@Autowired
public WeatherService(WeatherRepository weatherRepository){
    this.weatherRepository = weatherRepository;
}

public void saveWeather(Weather weather){
    weatherRepository.save(weather);
}
}
```

I changed annotations, created configs, reconnected the database, but nothing helped.

Comment: hi & welcome! "I am trying to save an object of the Weather in the database" - looks normal! "but it is not saved and no errors are issued." this is strange! "What could be the problem?" ..since there are no errors, please: verify your (application + verification) database connection(s) (are identical)

Answer (score 0):

JPA repositories will be auto-configured during start of Spring Boot application.

First check if the auto-configuration found your `WeatherRepository`. In the application log you should see:

```
Finished Spring Data repository scanning in NNN ms. Found XXX JPA repository interfaces.
```

The number of repositories XXX should equals the actual number of JPA repositories in your application.

If the number is 0 then check the package of the main application class. For auto-configuration to work smoothly it should be something like:

```
package com.example;
```

because it will be the base package for scanning your application for JPA entities and repositories. The other classes should follow this convention using for example:

```
package com.example.jpa;
package com.example.mvc;
```